# Sort each do loop (alphabet) ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to sort on the alphabet in the code below, or do I have to do it in the controller?

below code shows all websites but I want to sort it on alphabet and sort on offline sites. So the offline sites are always up.

```
<% @websites.each_with_index do |website, index| %>
```

Comment: What is `@websites`? What exactly do you mean by "sort on alphabet"? (For example, is `@websites` a collection of `Website` records; and is there a database column such as `websites.name` that you want to sort by?) Is case sensitivity important?

Comment: Also, what exactly do you mean by *"I want to sort it on alphabet and sort on offline sites"*? Are you saying you want to filter for only the "offline" sites? (Again, is there a database column such as `websites.online`? Help us out here.) Or are you saying that the sort order should be alphabetical, but *in the case of a tie* then the "offline" site should appear on top?

Comment: Please provide all the information necessary to answer your question. Every answer that's been posted below is based on unnecessary guess work, because you haven't fully stated your requirements.

Comment: So basically @websites has a name, url and online column (online = true or false). So i want to sort it on alphabet (not case sensitive). But if online is false then that site has to be all up. Sorry for being not clear. My quistion was more meant as in: "is it smarted to sort in controller or can i just do it in the each loop here"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have fields like `offline: true`, `name: <string>` at the `Website` model:

```
<% @websites.order(offline: :desc, name: :desc).each_with_index do |website, index| %>
```

However, you're likely retrieving `@websites` in the controller, so better apply that `order` condition in the controller/model scope/anywhere outside the view.

Answer (score 1):

`<% @websites.sort.each_with_index do |website, index| %>` if @websites is an array.
`<% @websites.order('title ASC').each_with_index do |website, index| %>` if activerecord,here title refers the column which we want to sort.